# VBA duplicate value (not using data validation)

Tags: excel, vba, events, duplicates, excel-2010

I have a question regarding catching a user for entering duplicate values in a sheet. We are unable to use data validation because cut/copy/paste throws out the data validation and allows them to enter the dupe value. I was originally using this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'******problem when copying entire row and pasting into new row, enables user to paste dupe Box ID #******

'Defining variables in Mailroom
Dim WS As Worksheet, EvalRange As Range
       
'Range to check for duplicates
Set EvalRange = Worksheets("Mailroom").Range("Box_ID_Number")
      
'Checking if entered value is in the defined range; also if cell is empty exit macro
If Intersect(Target, EvalRange) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

'If user enters dupe value in specified range then error message pops up and event is undone
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, Target.Value) > 1 Then
    MsgBox Target.Value & " already appears as a Box ID Number. Please enter a unique ID."
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

The code works fine for keeping a user from typing a dupe value in the column for "Box ID Number." The problem I am having is that if the user is to copy a Box ID Number from a column and another cell from a different column, they are able to paste a Dupe Value that the `_SheetChange` does not catch.  When we were first creating the code for this we were disabling cut/copy/paste functions; however, others using the sheet apparently still need that function for other portions of the sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need the ... Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 part?  That's what's preventing the function from catching duplicate when pasting two or more cells.

Comment: Tried taking out the "Or Target.Cells.Count>1" this gives me error 13 for "type mismatch" highlighting "If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, Target.Value) >1 Then"

Comment: Instead of using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`, try using `sh.find()`. If your resulting range is Nothing, it's a unique value, otherwise, it's a dupe.

Comment: sh.find() gives me an "Object does not support this property or method" error

Comment: Because `.Find` is a method belonging to the `Range` object and not the `Worksheet`. Search for some examples in internet on how to use this method. You need to `Set` some range object to get the `.Find` result. I always find it difficult to use this method, just because I don't remember how to do it properly... :)

Comment: Since you only care for the one column you could e.g. `Set Target =
Intersect(EvalRange, Target)` right after you set `EvalRange` and work wit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your users actually need to change only one cell at a time, I think the below thing should work (it's only the bottom part of your code):

```
If Intersect(Target, EvalRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

'Check if only one cell in "Box_ID_Number" is changed
If Intersect(Target, EvalRange).Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "One cell at a once please."
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, Intersect(Target, EvalRange)) > 1 Then
    MsgBox Target.Value & " already appears as a Box ID Number. Please enter a unique ID."
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

I have removed `Or Target.Cells.Count > 1` and instead of `CountIf(EvalRange, Target.Value)` in my version you see `CountIf(EvalRange, Intersect(Target, EvalRange))`. IF `Intersect(Target, EvalRange))` is not one cell, you would again get Type Mismatch (13) error. Therefore, to prevent it, I've implemented the additional check you see.

Comment: I really like your logic.  I tried your code and am getting an error when I still try to copy and paste more than 1 cell.  The error reads "Run-Time error '13: Type Mismatch"

When I debug it highlights `MsgBox Target.Value & " already appears as Box ID Number. Please enter a unique ID."`

Comment: Try testing: instead of `Target.Value` use `Intersect(Target, EvalRange)`.

Comment: Also you can try [xificurC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1688998/xificurc) suggestion in a comment under your main question. That looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

@ZygD ! nailed it with `Intersect(Target, EvalRange)`

Finished code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    'Defining variables in Mailroom
    Dim WS As Worksheet, EvalRange As Range

    'Range to check for duplicates
    Set EvalRange = Worksheets("Mailroom").Range("Box_ID_Number")

    If Intersect(Target, EvalRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'Check if only one cell in Box_ID_Number is changed at a time
    If Intersect(Target, EvalRange).Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to modify greater than 1 Box ID Number at a time.  Please select one Box ID Row."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
     Exit Sub
    End If`

    'check for dupe value in Box ID Number Column; if copy and pasting entire row, dupe check still holds
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EvalRange, Intersect(Target, EvalRange)) > 1 Then
        MsgBox Intersect(Target, EvalRange) & " already appears as a Box ID Number. Please enter a unique ID."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```